# How to indicate where you are taking something out of?

Tags: grammar, particles

If I wanted to say that I am taking meat out of the fridge, would I say 冷蔵庫に肉を出す, or should I use a different particle other than に after 冷蔵庫?

Answer (score 2):

I would say:

> 冷蔵庫から肉を取り出す。

に is a tricky particle. When someone is giving you something or doing you a favor, it can be used where we would use the word "from" in English. In most cases, however, "from" is translated as から, and in this case using に makes it sound like you're putting meat into the fridge rather than taking it out.